# Sonar-scala and default scala not working together

Tags: scala, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am currently using SonarQube 8.9 LTS
I have tried to install sonar-scala https://github.com/sonar-scala/sonar-scala in extensions/plugins folder, but I am facing error like as below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are two languages declared with the same key 'scala' declared by the plugins 'scala' and 'sonarscala'. Please uninstall one of the conflicting plugins.
```

Could someone who worked with sonar scala confirm, is there no way I can keep both default scala rules and sonar scala work together in parallel? uninstalling existing sonarway scala is a risk for me